# How to make a radio button selected using its value

Tags: jquery, html

In my code i am using a group of radio button having same id and name for all of the radio buttons.. but its value is different...

I have that value of the radio button that i want to be selected.. how can select that radio button using the value i have.
consider an example..

```
 <input name="newColorCode" id="newColorCode" type="radio" value="color_code_LightViolet"/>
<input name="newColorCode" id="newColorCode" type="radio" value="color_code_red"/>
<input name="newColorCode" id="newColorCode" type="radio" value="color_code_green"/>
```

i have the value color_code_green.. how can i make the corresponding radio button selected using jquery????

i tried this

```
       $('input:radio[value=color_code_green]').checked=true;
```

but its not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, ids must be unique in the whole DOM. So having 3 radios with `id="newColorCode"` is wrong. So start by removing those id attributes or provide unique ones for each button. Then to answer your question:

```
$(':radio[value="color_code_green"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jYgmA/1/).

The reason your code doesn't work is because the `$(..)` function returns an array of jQuery wrapped DOM elements for which the `checked` property which you are trying to set is simply not defined. So you could use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function in order to do this to all elements returned by your selector.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in JavaScript also:

```
function getSelectedRadio(buttonGroup) {
   // returns the array number of the selected radio button or -1 if no button is selected
   if (buttonGroup[0]) { // if the button group is an array (one button is not an array)
      for (var i=0; i<buttonGroup.length; i++) {
         if (buttonGroup[i].checked) {
            return i
         }
      }
   } else {
      if (buttonGroup.checked) { return 0; } // if the one button is checked, return zero
   }
   // if we get to this point, no radio button is selected
   return -1;
} // Ends the "getSelectedRadio" function

function getSelectedRadioValue(buttonGroup) {
   // returns the value of the selected radio button or "" if no button is selected
   var i = getSelectedRadio(buttonGroup);
   if (i == -1) {
      return "";
   } else {
      if (buttonGroup[i]) { // Make sure the button group is an array (not just one button)
         return buttonGroup[i].value;
      } else { // The button group is just the one button, and it is checked
         return buttonGroup.value;
      }
   }
} // Ends the "getSelectedRadioValue" function
```